# What will be the best alternative for NIS authentication?

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

Please provide me the best alternative for NIS ? As I have currently using NIS + AD authentication but we want to set up a new authentication system. Is there any alternative for  NIS and it is supporting a new OS like Centos 7 + Suse 15 + RHEL 7. Also, match the ssid and UUID and migrate the existing NIS account to the new authentication system.

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly reformulate the question so that it's not asking for people's _opinion_ of what may be "the best NIS"? We generally close questions that are ["opinion based"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an LDAP-based identity management system.

Both CentOS and RedHat provide a sophisticated service, namely **Red Hat Identity Management (IdM)**, to manage identity authentication. It is more powerful than NIS. FYI, NIS entries can be easily imported into IdM stores.

See [Linux Domain Identity, Authentication, and Policy Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/introduction).

Because of the LDAP backend of IdM, it can be extended across various Linux distributions. You can still utilize LDAP if you don't want the RedHat IdM running on your SUSE system.

See [Authentication Server and Client](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/42.1/security/html/book.security/cha.security.auth.html).

In case you are not familiar with LDAP, there are many resouces which could be helpful.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldap
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87994/389268

Answer (score 2):

The usual replacement for NIS servers are LDAP servers providing NSS maps based on schema defined in [RFC 2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307). On the Unixoid/Linux system you need PAM modules for authentication and NSS modules for map access.

Two free software solutions are [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org) and my own [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com).

See also my longer answer:

[How to only allow users and/or groups access certain client machines that are connected to an openldap server?](https://serverfault.com/a/922689/479197)